# How do I solve this garbled code in my code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I run a Python program, but the Chinese in the program is displayed in gibberish, how can i solve？
[image]

Comment: Which part is gibberish?

Comment: @danh hello,danh ,the gibberish is "璇疯緭鍏ヤ竴涓矾寰勶細" in the last line of picture.What should I configure？

Comment: Is this an encoding issue? Try setting `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows` within VS Code Settings to `["-NoExit", "/c", "chcp.com 65001"]` ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19837#issuecomment-291023457)).